# pop3 hotmail settings for Alpine email program?

Tags: pop3, hotmail, alpine-mail

I have searched the web for the correct settings to be able to access my hotmail with Alpine email client - it is a program you use from the terminal (i am using Linux). So far I have no success. I have seen many examples for Gmail but no pop3 examples for hotmail. I know it is possible to access you hotmail via pop3 as I have 2 other programs that do it but the settings they use don't work in Alpine, has anyone had success?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a hotmail account to verify this, but try

For receiving set your Inbox Path to:

```
pop3.live.com:995/ssl/novalidate-cert/POP3/user=username@hotmail.com
```

For sending:

```
Use SMTP Server = smtp.live.com:587/tls/user=my_email@hotmail.com
```